# Is System.Threading.Semaphore weak?

Tags: c#, semaphore

There are two types of Semaphore

**Strong Semaphore:** maintains an order internally.

**Weak semaphore:** which does not provide any ordered access to a critical section which can cause starvation.

“There is no guaranteed order, such as FIFO or LIFO, in which blocked threads enter the semaphore.” from MSDN remarks in System.Threading.Semaphore.

I would like to confirm what type of semaphore implementation is provided by .Net Framework ?

Comment: It is not up to the framework, the CLR host marries the semaphore to the platform.  Underlying hosting interface is [IHostSemaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/ihostsemaphore-interface).  In practice a wrapper for the OS provided primitive.  Refer to the OS docs for details, like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129(v=vs.85).aspx) for Windows.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    static int count = 0;
    static Semaphore writerSem = new Semaphore(0, 10);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread[] readers = new Thread[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < readers.Length; i++)
        {
            readers[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Reader));
            readers[i].Name = "Reader: " + i;
            readers[i].Start();
        }
        Thread writer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Writer));

        writer.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < readers.Length; i++)
        {
            readers[i].Join();
        }
        writer.Join();

    }
    static void Reader()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            writerSem.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine(count + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);                 
        }
    }
    static void Writer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            count++;
            writerSem.Release(10);
            Thread.Sleep(1000); 
        }
    }
```

I have tested it by writing this program. It is just confirmed that System.Threading.Semaphore is implemented as **Weak Semaphore**.

[image: Output]